# Postgres calculate average using distinct IDs‚ values also distinct

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a postgres query that is supposed to calculate an average value based on a set of values. This set of values should be based on DISTINCT ID's.

The query is the following:

```
#{context.answers_base}
SELECT
    stores.name as store_name,
    answers_base.question_name as question_name,
    answers_base.question_id as question_id,
    (sum(answers_base.answer_value) / NULLIF(count(answers_base.answer_id),0)) as score, # <--- this line is calculating wrong
    sum(answers_base.answer_value) as score_sum,
    count(answers_base.answer_id) as question_answer_count,
    count(DISTINCT answers_base.answer_id) as answer_count
FROM answers_base
  INNER JOIN stores ON stores.id = answers_base.store_id
WHERE answers_base.answer_value IS NOT NULL AND answers_base.question_type_id = :question_type_id
      AND answers_base.scale = TRUE
#{context.filter_answers}
GROUP BY stores.name, answers_base.question_name, answers_base.question_id, answers_base.sort_order
ORDER BY stores.name, answers_base.sort_order
```

The thing is, that on the indicated line `(sum(answers_base.answer_value) / NULLIF(count(answers_base.answer_id),0))` some values are counted more than once.

Part of the solution is making it DISTINCT based on ID, like so:
`(sum(answers_base.answer_value) / NULLIF(count(DISTINCT answers_base.answer_id),0))`

This will result in an average that divided by the right number, but here the sum it's dividing is still wrong.

Doing the following (make sum() DISTINCT) does not work, for the reason that values are not unique. The values are either 0 / 25 / 50 / 75 / 100, so different IDs might contain 'same' values.
`(sum(DISTINCT answers_base.answer_value) / NULLIF(count(DISTINCT answers_base.answer_id),0))`

How would I go about making this work?

Here are simplified versions of the table structures.

Table **Answer**

| ID | answer_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Feb 01, 2022 |
| 2 | Mar 02, 2022 |
| 3 | Mar 13, 2022 |
| 4 | Mar 21, 2022 |

Table **AnswerRow**

| ID | answer_id | answer_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |
| 4 | 2 | 75 |
| 5 | 2 | 100 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 25 |
| 8 | 4 | 25 |
| 9 | 4 | 100 |
| 10 | 4 | 50 |

Answer 1' `answer_rows`:
25 + 50 + 50 -> `average = 125 / 3`

Answer 2' `answer_rows`:
75 + 100 + 0 -> `average = 175 / 3`

Answer 3' `answer_rows`:
25 -> `average = 25 / 1`

Answer 4' `answer_rows`:
25 + 100 + 50 -> `average = 175 / 3`

For some reason, we get duplicate answer_rows in the calculation.

Example of the problem; for `answer_id=1` we have the following answer_rows in the calculation, giving us a different average:

| ID | answer_id | answer_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 50 |
| **3** | 1 | 50 |
| **3** | 1 | 50 |
| **3** | 1 | 50 |

Result: `25 + 50 + 50 + 50 + 50 + 50 -> 275 / 6`
Desired result: `25 + 50 + 50 -> 125 / 3`

Making answer_row_id distinct (see beginning of post) makes it possible for me to get:
`25 + 50 + 50 + **50 + 50 + 50** -> 275 / **3**`
But not
`25 + 50 + 50 -> 275 / 3`

What I would like to achieve is having a calculation that selects `answer_row` distinctly based on its ID, and *those* answer_rows will be used both for calculation `x` and `y` in calculation `average -> x / y`.

answers_base is the following (simplified):

```
WITH answers_base as (
  SELECT
      answers.id as answer_id,
      answers.store_id as store_id,
      answer_rows.id as answer_row_id,
      question_options.answer_value as answer_value
  FROM answers
      INNER JOIN answer_rows ON answers.id = answer_rows.answer_id
      INNER JOIN stores ON stores.id = answers.store_id
  WHERE answers.status = 0
)
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre] so you join two tables, there can be multiple rows, running the query with out Group by you see the actual number

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question, because this appears to be a very strange interpretation of the word "average"?... You want to first get a list of unique values, and *then* take the average from the unique list? The end result isn't really an average, at all -- so I'm not clear why that would be useful.

Comment: we need a sample of your two tables, the the database is for this query not necessary, you canfurther reduce the number of columns that are not needed for this query.

Comment: Apologies for not creating a good post to begin with, I completely understand the issue! I edited the question and added the table structures and relations, as well as the rest of the SQL (#{context.answers_base}). Also a bit better explanation of the problem. Hopefully this helps understanding it better.

Comment: *For some reason, we get duplicate answer_rows in the calculation.* -- Right, OK, now I understand the question. Obviously, just **fixing the data** would be preferable to a hacky workaround, but I appreciate that this might not be possible/practical.

Comment: What is table `stores`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be best solved with a [*window function*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html). Something along the lines of

```
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY answer_rows.id ORDER BY answer_rows.created_at DESC) AS duplicate_answers
   ...
WHERE
   answer_rows.duplicate_answers = 1
```

This would filter out multiple rows with the same `id`, and only keep one entry. (I chose the "first by `created_at`", but you could change this to whatever logic suits you best.)

A benefit to this approach is that it makes the rationale behind the logic clear, contained and re-usable.